# Why was Lord Shiva a vairagi in the starting and then turned into a grihastha?

Tags: shiva, parvati, sati-goddess

Lord Shiva was a vairagi in the starting, then why did he turn into a grihastha by marrying Goddess Sati and then her reincarnation Goddess Parvati?

Comment: It's a good thing what I came accros is this ; Lord bhramha, Lord Shiva, and Lord Vishnu are three brothers, son of one they worship ... He is the creator of univers, they are the tree powers of him as you can see in different old pictures of them they inchant their fathers name whom they never saw.

Comment: @Kuldeep : could you please share the source and how this comment is related to my question?

Answer (score 2):

Lord Shiva (Rudra) was married from the beginning. *Puranas* like Bhagavatam, Vishnu Puran, etc. give the account how Rudra was born from Brahma and married Sati, the daughter of Daksha, as his wife. Below is a description from Vishnu Purana:

> Later on Brahma commenced the process of creation. During that time he desired a child like himself. Then a blue-red colored child appeared on his lap and started crying as he wanted a name. Brahma named him Rudra, but he still continued to cry. So Brahma gave him another seven names. They are: Bhava, Sarva, Ishana, Pashupati, Bhima, Ugra and Mahadeva. **Rudra married to Sati, the daughter of Daksha**. Sati getting angry on Daksha gave up her life and reborn as Parvati, the daughter of Himavat and Mena. Then Hara (Shiva) again married Parvati. [VP - 1.8.2-14]

But after casting of the body by Sati, Lord Shiva resumed His ascetic form. However, the demon Tarakasura had the boon that he would only be killed by Siva's son. May be he thought Siva was an ascetic and won't marry and hence won't have a son. But the gods requested Himavat to accept Parvati as his daughter and then suggested Kamadeva to afflict Shiva with desire for marriage. But Shiva burned Kama to ashes. Then the gods pleaded Shiva to marry Parvati and begot a son so that Tarakasura can be killed. So Lord Shiva told them:

> *nocita hi vidhānaṃ vai vivāhakaraṇaṃ nṛṇām
>
>   mahānigaḍasaṃjño hi vivaha druḍhabandhanaḥ
>
>   kusaṃgā bahavo loke strisaṃgastatra cādhikaḥ
>
>   uddharetsakalebaindhairna strisamgātpramucyate* [Shiva Pu. - 2.24.60,61]
>
> **Meaning**
>   As far as possible, man should not marry. Marriage known as chain is a very strong bondage. Usually there are many *kusanga* (bad association) in the world, but association with women is the worst of all. One can free himself from other bad associations, but cannot free himself from a woman.

But **because Lord Shiva is fond of and saviour of devotees, instead of His unwillingness, He agreed to the gods' proposal and became a *grihasta* (family man)**:

> *bhaktadhino'hamevāsmi taddaśātsarvakāryakrut
>
>   ayathocitakartā hi prasiddhau bhubanatraye
>
>   nāsti yadyāpi me kaścidihakaraṇe ruciḥ
>
>   vivahayiṣye girijāṃ putrotpādanahetave* [Sv. Pu. -2.24.67,75]
>
> **Meaning**
>   As I am under my devotees, I do all their work. Even I am famous in all the three worlds as someone who gets the odd jobs done. So even though I have no desire and liking in these things, I will marry Parvati for the purpose of begetting a son.

The Mahabharat has a different version of the story where the gods stop Shiva from begotting a son as it would be fierce enough to devour entire world. So Shiva draws up his semen and hence called as *Urdhareta* (one who has taken his semen up) since that day. Generally the yogu ascetics are known as *urdharetas*.

Comment: Please share the sources, Shiva Puran says that Vishnu and Brahma were created from Aadi Anant JyotirStambha of Shiva. When there was a dispute between Brahma and Vishnu about who is the supreme, at that time Shiva appeared as Jyotirstambha and asked both of them to reach start and end of it. Vishnu traveled downwards to reach end and Brahma traveled upwards to reach beginning, but both of them failed and considered there is no end of Shiva and asked Shiva to guide them. In this story Brahma lied that he reached beginning, So Shiva banned his worships in Hinduism,

Comment: so `how Rudra was born from Brahma` as they were created from `Aadi Anant JyotirStambha of Shiva` ?

Comment: @SidM yes,you are right about the origin story. Some *shaiva puranas*  do mention Brahma and Vishnu originated from Shiva. But that Shiva means the supreme entity Brahman, and the different Rudras that originated from Brahma are not the supreme God. There exists a subtle difference. The Linga Purana ch. 22, Shiva Pu. Rudra Samhita Ch. 15, Kurma Pu. Ch. 1.10, Vishnu Pu. Ch. 1.8, etc. have the story regarding origin of Rudra from Brahma after his battle with Vishnu was over.

Comment: @jabhar : can you please share the sources about which you are saying?

Comment: these sources will also do to support your answer `The Linga Purana ch. 22, Shiva Pu. Rudra Samhita Ch. 15, Kurma Pu. Ch. 1.10, Vishnu Pu. Ch. 1.8`

Comment: i think it is urdhvaretas, not urdharetas

Comment: Lord Shiva as semen

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it happened. 
Nothingness (ShivA) -> Vishnu -> Brahma -> Shankara (Sakaar roop of Lord ShivA).
It is foolish to say Lord Shiva is the son of Brahma Dev. Just as Lord Ram is born from Kaushalya, similarly Lord Shiva took birth in this material world through Brahma. Lord Shiva's nirakaar nirgun roop is unborn, but his Physical Sakaar roop is born or took place.

Shiva = Shiv + Adi Shakti (Material/Prakriti). 
When Shiva separated him from Adi Shakti, nothing was left, no material possesion hence only thing left was Vairag.

Answer (score 0):

Shiv did not want to marry. He was totally against marriage and love but then one day a demon named Tarkasur asked him for a boon that only Shiv's son can kill him. Shiv did not have a choice but give him the boon. Tarkasur knew that he couldn't ask for amrit. So, he took boon from Shiva as he was a vairagi and couldn't marry and get a child. But then, what has born has to die. So sati was born. Shiva did not want to fall in love with her but couldn't help it. His love is pure towards her.But destiny lied somewhere else and sati decided to die.( why did she is another story). Shiv cried like anything over her death as he loved her. Nobody could separate sati from shiv. So she took another birth to meet her love once again. She was Parvati now. And once again Shiv and shakti were together. Then Kartikeya was born and he killed Tarkasur

Comment: Please cite sources.